# How should I mention the phantomjs path in gruntfile.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, gruntjs, phantomjs, protractor

The JSON formatted key, `'phantomjs.binary.path'` is not supported in Grunt

```
grunt.initConfig ({
protractor: {
  options: {
    configFile: './protractor-conf.js',
    keepAlive: true,
    noColor: false
  },

  phantomjs: {
    options: {
        args: {
          capabilities: {

            browserName: "phantomjs",
            'phantomjs.binary.path': './node_modules/.bin/phantomjs',
          },
        },
    }
  },

},
```

[image: enter link description here]